# Django - create nested html list from list of dictionary objects

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Python list of dictionary in the form e.g.

```
[{'Parent':'top', 'Child':'obj1', 'Level':0},
 {'Parent':'obj1', 'Child':'obj2', 'Level':1},
 {'Parent':'obj1', 'Child':'obj3', 'Level':1},
 {'Parent':'obj2', 'Child':'obj4', 'Level':2},
 {'Parent':'obj4', 'Child':'obj5', 'Level':3}]
```

I want to write this out as a nested html list based on the Parent e.g.

- obj1

  - obj2

    - obj4

      - obj5
  - obj3

How can I do this in a Django template

Comment: Why are you creating a flat dictionary?  What's the "original" information?

Comment: Not really a helpful answer.  Can you **update** the question to show the table and the query?  I suspect that the query (or model) can be fixed to be properly nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
def make_list(d):
    def append_children(parent, d):
        children = [[x['Child']] for x in d if x['Parent'] == parent[0]]
        if children:
            parent.append(children)
            for child in children:
                append_children(child, d)

    results = [[x['Child']] for x in d if x['Parent'] == 'top']
    for parent in results:
        append_children(parent, d)

    return results
```

Pass the list into this function and then apply `unordered_list` filter to the result. The disadvantage of this method is that `<ul>` list is created even for one element (`<ul><li>elem</li></ul>`), but you can alter display as you like with CSS.

If you want clearer HTML you should write a custom tag or filter for that.